# Laravel $push->getAdapter()->getResponse() is blank for iphone

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using Laravel push notification library, for pushing notification.
However, i can easly get responses for GCM responses for Android Device.
But unable to get APNS response.

```
$message = PushNotification::Message("New Messages",$params['payload']);
        $collection = PushNotification::app('appNameIOS')
                ->to($params['reg_id'])
                ->send($message);
    foreach ($collection->pushManager as $push) {
        $response = $push->getAdapter()->getResponse();
    }
```

Comment: $params['reg_id'] is single device token or an array of tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed proper format as below:-

```
//iOS app
PushNotification::app(['environment' => 'development',
        'certificate' => '/path/to/certificate.pem',
        'passPhrase'  => 'password',
        'service'     => 'apns']);

$devices = PushNotification::DeviceCollection(array(
    PushNotification::Device('token', array('badge' => 5)),
    PushNotification::Device('token1', array('badge' => 1)),
    PushNotification::Device('token2')
));
$message = PushNotification::Message('Message Text',array(
    'badge' => 1,
    'sound' => 'example.aiff',

    'actionLocKey' => 'Action button title!',
    'locKey' => 'localized key',
    'locArgs' => array(
        'localized args',
        'localized args',
    ),
    'launchImage' => 'image.jpg',

    'custom' => array('custom data' => array(
        'we' => 'want', 'send to app'
    ))
));

$collection = PushNotification::app('appNameIOS')
    ->to($devices)
    ->send($message);

// get response for each device push
foreach ($collection->pushManager as $push) {
    $response = $push->getAdapter()->getResponse();
}
```